# C - working with specific bits of string/int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, c89

For the project i'm working on, a "word" is defined as 10 bit length, and as according to what my program does, I need to update specific bits in this word, with binary numbers (of course up to the limit of the length of the bits). My problem is that I don't know how to create these bits, and after that how to read them.

For example, "word" is set like this:

```
bits 0-1 - representing something A - can get values between 0-3.

bits 2-3 - representing something B - can get values between 0-3.

bits 4-5 - C - values 0-3.

bits 6-9 - D - values 0-15.
```

and as my program running, I need to decide what to fill in each group of bit. After that, when my word is completely full, I need to analyze the results, meaning to go over the full word, and understand from bits 0-1 what A is representing, from bits 2-3 what B is representing, and so on..

another problem is that bit number 9 is the most significant bit, which mean the word is filling up from bits 6-9 to 4-5 to 2-3 to 0-1, and later on printed from bit 9 to 0, and not as a regular array.

I tried to do it with struct of bit-fields, but the problem is that while a "word" is always 10 bits length, the sub-division as mentioned above is only one example of a "word". it can also be that the bits 0-1 representing something, and bits 2-9 something else.

I'm a bit lost and don't know how to do it, and I'll be glad if someone can help me with that.
Thanks!

Comment: Look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090326/how-to-extract-specific-bits-from-a-number-in-c?rq=1). You'll have to use bitmasks for what you want to achieve.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19376742/694733) is for a different question, but it should give you an example of generic way to set bits without struct bit-fields.

Comment: Why are you using C89 if you are learning C? Don't use old, outdated crap sources of learning.

Comment: You can use bitfield structure and union combinations to achive same.

Answer (score 1):

Just model a "word" as an `uint16_t`, and set the appropriate bits.

Something like this:

```
typedef uint16_t word;

word word_set_A(word w, uint8_t a)
{
  w &= ~3;
  return w | (a & 3);
}

uint8_t word_get_A(word w)
{
  return w & 3;
}

word word_set_B(word w, uint8_t b)
{
  w &= ~0xc0;
  return w | ((b & 3) << 2);
}
```

... and so on.

Comment: Set functions should mask out old values in `w`, if they are non-zero.

Comment: `word_set_A` should return `(w & ~3) | (a & 3)`

Comment: I have never heard of uint16_t. Is it compatable with ANSI C?

Comment: @DanShul There is formally nothing called "ANSI C" any longer, that term is usually used to refer to the old C89 standard. `uint16_t` was introduced with `stdint.h` in the year 1999. It is not compatible with C98 but with modern, standard C.

Comment: @Dan It's part of `stdint.h` since C99, but many C89 compilers provide it since it's just a bunch of typedefs and constants.

Comment: @DanShul It's in `inttypes.h` but also available with `stdint.h` and is very much part of the standard (C99).

Comment: @DanShul An `unsigned short` will do if you can't use `uint16_t`.